# Data Filter does not display labels correctly in mobile or tablet sizes

Tags: html, css, tablet, responsive, smartphone

This is my first post so please be nice. I  have been struggling getting this data filter to work correctly in mobile and tablet format.

themovingpicture org au / archive (Sorry can't post more than 2 links and images are important to explain problem)

Everything looks perfect on desktop and resizing in chrome everything stays as it should and the label comes up however in mobile when tapped all I get is a grey block. I've identified the grey block that comes up on mobile as being in my layout.css

```
.portfolio-wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative !important;
  background: #666;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#filters li span {
  display: block;
  padding:5px 20px;   
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I originally got the code from here:

Create a simple responsive portfolio page with filtering and hover effect.

I've tried removing and editing parts (e.g. removing media queries, removing normal.css etc.) of the CSS but just can't figure out how to make it display the same way on mobile and tablet as on desktop.

I've attached two images below showing the same code being displayed on desktop in Chrome versus a display in Safari on an iPhone 6

[image: Desktop Display]

[image: Mobile Display]

Comment: What is your question? What is exactly the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Image examples have been added to explain problem.

Comment: make a jsfiddle of your code

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a screen size problem as iPhone6 owns a little larger screen then that one your testing on your Desktop and the browser recognize as being a Tablet screen. Also, looks like you've putted your label set up inside some media query block.

You can fix it by making your labels formatting global (not inside of media queries blocks) and changing your media queries values making your small screen even more large then your extra small screen.

Exemple:

```
/*Bootstrap's default small screen minimum size*/
@media (min-width: 655px) {
...
}
```

You may change this value to make phablets being recognized as regular smartphones.

```
/*Value changed*/
@media (min-width: 820px) {
...
}
```